# Having known vs Knowing

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. Having known him for many years, I'm sure he will reject the offer.
> 2. Knowing him for many years, I'm sure he will reject the offer.

Which one is grammatically correct? If both, what is the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples have the same meaning.

> Having known him for many years, I'm sure he will reject the offer.

is a bit nuanced and possibly expresses a closer relationship or understanding, than

> Knowing him for many years, I'm sure he will reject the offer.